# Issue with saving specific data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have an issue with needing to save some specific data on user creation and unsure as to how to approach it.

I have three models, User, Portfolio, and Account. User hasOne Portfolio, Portfolio hasMany Account. I'm trying to figure out how to save Account data when a User is being created. But this isn't where it ends.

Currently on User creation, a Portfolio is also created after the user is successfully created. Using these 3 lines in the UsersController.php file:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data['User'])) {
            $this->request->data['Portfolio']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;
            if ($this->User->Portfolio->save($this->request->data['Portfolio'])) {
```

The accounts table is fairly meager, id, portfolio_id, currency, and amount. On user creation, multiple rows need to be added to the accounts table, one for each currency we support (at the moment 2, will likely be more later), and each row could have different amounts.

My problems are two-fold, first, how do I create this new data in the user registration form? And second, what do I do with it once a user is successfully created?

I'll admit I haven't done much research on this as I don't even really know what to search for that would find this particular problem. If you need anymore info please just ask and I'll edit this post to supply it.

EDIT:
After following advice to use saveAll to save all the data and associated data, I've run into another issue. My portfolio table is the very definition of slim at the moment. Right now, it only holds a user_id and that's it. So when I run the save operation, there is no data in the request->data array to signify a Portfolio needs to be saved, as the only data that needs to be saved comes from the user_id which can only be obtained after a user is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [CakePHP's saveMany()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array).  This is what you're looking for.  And any of the other minor related questions can be answered by this page too.

Comment: So this kind of tells me how to structure my data on my form and how to save it, but where do I perform the save operation? Do I do it inside that if statement for saving the Portfolio above? Because that just seems messy, that'll be three if statements one inside the other. Would there by anyway to leverage the models AfterSave callback to do this by any chance?

Comment: You literally just have a single line - a single saveAll will save all 3 models.  I suggest reading the very in-depth online documentation that is the CakePHP book.

Comment: you only use $this->User->Portfolio->save($this->request->data) instead of $this->User->Portfolio->save($this->request->data['Portfolio']) because `Portfolio` are already link to your modal.

Comment: So I'm having a slight issue with this, I've added the new issue to the problem above.

Comment: If it's empty data you're looking to save, then use afterSave() to add a Portfolio row.

Comment: How would I use afterSave? As far as I can tell it only has a boolean if a new record was created, and the options passed to the save call. How do I get the id of the user created for the Portfolio? And then, I need the portfolio_id to create the accounts, how do I get that during the saveAll call?

Comment: Read the very thorough online documentation that walks you through exactly this scenario.